# Auto Button cycle

Tags: javascript, html

I was able to get the button working on click with a delay making it semi-auto, but I need it not to pause after one click. This is what I have so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body>
  <h1>JavaScript</h1>  
  <img id="light" src="./assets/red.jpg">
  <button onClick="changeLights(changelights, 1000)">Change Lights</button>
  <button onClick="clearInterval(changeLights)">Stop Lights!</button>
  <script> 
    var list = ["./assets/red.jpg","./assets/redamber.jpg", "./assets/green.jpg","./assets/amber.jpg" ];
    var index = 0;
    function changeLights() {
      index = index + 1;
      if (index == list.length) 
        index = 0;
      var image = document.getElementById('light');
      image.src = list[index]; 
    } 
    setInterval(nxt,200);

  </script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: This code will not do what you say it does. `nxt` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: `changeLights(changelights, 1000)`  this isn't correct either.

Comment: any way i can fix this because thats what others have told me

Comment: What did they tell you?  The code I pointed out is obviously, glaringly wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the user to be able to click a button to start looping through the images, and stop it by clicking the other button. Here is code to do that based on your code. I've shown it for 2 images but it will work for a longer list as well...

```js
var keepgoing = false;
var list = [
  "https://s22.postimg.org/84255zdkt/bulboff.jpg",
  "https://s22.postimg.org/5b8xlyd8d/bulbon.jpg"
];
var index = 0;
var image = document.getElementById('light');

function startLights() {
  if (keepgoing) return;
  keepgoing = true;
  changeLights();
}

function changeLights() {
  if (keepgoing) {
    setTimeout(changeLights, 500);
    index = (index + 1) % list.length;
    image.src = list[index];
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onClick="startLights();">Change Lights</button>
  <button onClick="keepgoing = false;">Stop Lights!</button>
</div>
<img id="light" style="width:100px;" src="https://s22.postimg.org/84255zdkt/bulboff.jpg">
```